# How to read a line using scanf() in C?

Tags: c

I need to read a line as input using scanf() and then just print it using printf(). 
I tried using `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",sen);` and

```
printf("%[^\n]%*c", sen);
```

This is what I get as output:

```
 %[^
]
```

Can anyone point out what I'm wrong?

The following code will take three inputs, a character, a string, and a line. After that, just print the three data. But I'm having trouble with reading the line using `scanf()`.

```
  { 
    char ch,s[10],sen[25];

    scanf("%c",&ch);
    scanf("%s",s);
    scanf("\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",sen);

    printf("%c\n",ch);
    printf("%s\n",s);
    printf("%[^\n]%*c", sen);
  }
```

Expected output will look something like this:

```
C
Language
Welcome To C!!
```

What I got:

```
C
Language
 %[^
]
```

Comment: Why do you need to use scanf?

Comment: `printf("%[^\n]%*c", sen);`-->`printf("%s", sen);`

Comment: @Broman It is a challenge. I can only use scanf() and printf().

Comment: There are some similarities between `scanf` and `printf` but they need to be studied separately.

Comment: Reading a line with `scanf` is like driving a nail with a screwdriver.  You might be able to get it to mostly work, but it's a pointless exercise, and totally the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using printf() to display the input of the user you use a normal "%s" sign, the      "%[^\n]%*c" is only used with scanf() since this function takes input only till the first space.

So when displaying using printf(), your code should be like this:

```
printf("%s", sen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep taking input character by character till you find a newline('\n').

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char s[100],c;
    int len=0;

    while(scanf("%c", &c)==1) { //==1 is to ensure you have not reached end of file(EOF)
        if(c== '\n')
            break;
        s[len++]=c;
    }
    s[len] = '\0'; //to mark end of the string.
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```